# Eloquent to raw query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to see what the raw version of my query looks like from my Eloquent query?

For example, if I have this Eloquent query:

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->take(10)->get();
```

How could I have it output the raw version of the query, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE votes > 100 LIMIT 10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw query output using `toSql()`:

```php
$myRawQuery = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->take(10)->toSql();
```

Or you can use `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` to output the latest queries you've run.

Comment: I think he wants the sql query without executing it

Comment: You have to call `toSql()` on the query, not the result.